# Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am currently converting my swift 2.3 code to swift 3 and I am getting the above error on the following line:

```
setSharedPassword(nil, account: account, completion: completion)
```

Would the appropriate solution be just to replace nil with ""? The error goes away when I do it. I am looking for an explanation. Please help.

Comment: Yeah if you replace `nil` with `""`, the error will go away. It seems that the method requires a password - I'm assuming no password is required?

Comment: Is this your own personal func?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your `setSharedPassword` func's first parameter is of type `String` then you will not be able to set this as `nil` because it is not optional. If you want to be able to set it as nil, then you could do something like this for your func:

```
func setSharedPassword(string: String?, account: ...)
```

The reason why "" works is because it is still a value for a String, just a value that has no characters.

Of course this answer is assuming this is your own func. If `setSharedPassword` is not yours, then you either need to come up with a String that represents no password, or just supply "" as before.